# Very early check-in in Frankfurt airport

Tags: check-in, lounges, frankfurt, korean-air

In some east-asian airports is possible to check-in several hours in advance, so that you can spend time more time inside the airside of the airport (so you can use the lounge for example).

I wonder if that is the case in the Frankfurt International Airport, for a flight from Korea Air.

Is it possible lets say check-in 5 hours before the flight departure and enter in the airside?

Comment: Have you asked the airline when check-in opens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends.

Typically the airline will you happily check you in as long as a counter is open regardless of when your flight is leaving.  If you were flying Lufthansa, you check in anytime since there is always a counter open. Unfortunately it looks like there is only one Korean flight from FRA per day, so you can't "piggy back" on an earlier flight.

Most international check in counters open 3-4 hours before departure, but it depends and is hard to predict. In some case (high status, premium class) they sometimes "sneak you in" early as a special service.

You can always check in online and get a mobile boarding pass (or print your own). If you don't have checked luggage, you can just go through customs and security anytime (on the same day). I did that on Tuesday from FRA (to the US) and didn't have to go to a check in counter at all.

See https://www.koreanair.com/global/en/offers-promotion/promotions-hidden/web-mobile-check-in.html and you can also ask the airline directly

Comment: According to the Korean Air website, their check-in desks are open from 16:00 to 18:45 every day.

Comment: @jcaron that's great to know, you mean in Frankfurt airport I suspect?

Comment: @vicenteadolfoboleasánchez indeed.

Comment: @jcaron you should have gotten the right answer